# Integral right and isosceles triangles with equal area and perimeter

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

There are many different tasks in pictures on the Internet. I found one picture and it interested me.

[image]

And two questions. The first. Did I write this system correctly? That is, to reformulate the problem in the form of two right triangles.

$$
\left\{\!\begin{aligned}
&  X^2+Y^2=Z^2  \\
&  A^2+B^2=C^2  \\
&  2XY=AB \\
&  2Y+2Z=A+B+C  
\end{aligned}\right. 
$$
And the second question... these are some ideas for solving such systems? Not numerical, but rather parametrization of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Where did you find this meme/problem?

The problem is asking for a right triangle and an isoceles triangle with the same area and permimeter.
This was asked and solved only recently by Hirakawa and Matsumura, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.09936. They showed using quite advanced techniques that there is a unique solution.
They give the equations they use there, which are different to yours but could be equivalent.

See also the video abstract: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iln_m7zymtw

Comment: I know about this job. But there is no parameterization of solutions. There, the curves are set and then the whole points are searched for on these curves. And I am interested in the parameterization of solutions.

Comment: @individ I don't understand what you mean by parameterization of solutions. If you are looking for integer solutions, there is only 1 solution (up to rescaling), so there is nothing to parameterize.

Comment: If there are infinitely many solutions. Then there must be a parameterization of the solutions. The formula itself is probably long, but it should be. And here is the task to find it.

Comment: Okay. I'll think about it later and write my opinion here.